# CSS Image Positioning

Tags: css

Say I have an image that has a width of 2000px.  The snazzy design part of my image starts at about 600px in and is 900px wide or so. What I want to do is to use this image as the background on a website and have the snazzy design centered and when you stretch the browser window, reveal the entire image still keeping the snazzy design centered.   How can I do this?  Also, putting the snazzy part in it's own layer above the background is not an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Guffa's answer, you can also use percentage and pixel values to position your background image:

```
/* Centered vertically, 200px down from the top of the page  */
background-position: 50% 200px;

/* 30px from the left edge, -10px from the top (shifted up beyond the top)  */
background-position: 30px -10px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can center the background image using the CSS `background-position` attribute:

```
background-position: top center;
```